# Boot loader below 128 GB

Tags: boot, partition, boot-loader, gparted

I have some old hardware where Linux can't boot if the bootlader is over 128 GB. The problem is that I don't know exactly how those 128 GB are considered.

So the first question is, are they considered like 131,072 MB or 128,000 MB ?

Then, do I use aligned by MiB or by cylinders in Gparted ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an address limit i.e. a number of bits. Thus this refers to real gigabytes (GiB) i.e. 2^37 bytes == 128 GiB == 131,072 MiB == 137438 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Hauke Laging has answered your first question, but I suggest that you make things simple for yourself and make the first partition the bootable one.

As for your second question, it shouldn't make much difference.

MiB alignment is a *relatively* recent convention. It can make access more efficient, and stop recent partitioning software from annoying you with warnings.

Cylinder alignment is a more traditional thing, but unless your hardware (and hard drive) is older than a decade or so, cylinder/head/sector geometry is probably not an issue, although, once again, most partitioning software will give warnings if partitions aren't aligned on cylinder boundaries.

The default settings that gparted uses are generally sensible (although I find the MiB alignment thing slightly annoying, especially when formatting small USB flash drives). You *can* make the 1st partition start on sector 1 (i.e. the first sector after the MBR and partition table), although the modern convention is to leave some extra space so that bootloaders like Grub can store stuff. Starting the 1st partition on sector 63 seems to be adequate, although if you *are* using MiB alignment you'll get a lot more space than that. :)